# Class, numpy, dataset file: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, typeerror

New to programming and trying to learn OOP and ML. Yes, taking on both concepts simultaneously has been an immense struggle yet enjoyable. I have run into this error and I am unsure how to fix it.

```
class DataInputOutput:
    def __init__(self, inputData, outputData):
        self.input = inputData
        self.output = outputData


class DTModel:
    def __init__(self, dataSetFile):
        dataset = arff.load(open(dataSetFile, 'r'))
        data = np.array(dataset['data'])

        inputs = data[:, :-1]  # All feature inputs except the last col
        outputs = data[:, -1]  # Last col of array which is the feature result

        trainInputs = inputs[:6000]  # First 6000 is training
        self.trainOutputs = outputs[:6000]
        self.trainingDataSet = dataset(inputData=trainInputs, outputData=self.trainOutputs)
```

Output: `self.trainingDataSet = self.dataset(inputData=trainInputs, outputData=self.trainOutputs)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

I was reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47679520/python3-programme-raising-typeerror-dict-object-is-not-callable) and threads alike. I've tried making changes such as:

```
dataset(inputData=[trainInputs], outputData=[self.trainOutputs] # adding brackets, "dict not callable" still occurs
```

Other changes I attempt to make result in the Pycharm error "Unresolved reference." Like doing:

```
= [dataset[inputData(trainInputs)] .... # inputData unresolved reference
```

Any other changes I try, Pycharm highlights the entire line. Maybe I am editing the wrong line and a change should be made somewhere like in `dataset` or `data`?

Complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./train1.py", line 81, in <module>
loaddata = DTModel("mydataset.arff")
File "./train1.py", line 31, in __init__
self.trainingDataSet = dataset(inputData=trainInputs, 
outputData=self.trainOutputs)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: `dataset` is a dictionary. What's your intent with calling it as though it were the constructor of `DataInputOutput`? What are you trying to do by writing `dataset(inputData=trainInputs, outputData=self.trainOutputs)`?

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: I don't know what you're end goal is, but it almost seems like you want `self.trainingDataSet = DataInputOutput(inputData=trainInputs, outputData=self.trainOutputs)`

Comment: @Carcigenicate My intent is to use `DataInputOutput`later on in another class that will provide various types of metrics like training accuracy, graphical plotting, etc.

Comment: @JohnSmith Well then see my last comment. This seems like a typo.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Ah. I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You complained that assigning a `dict` to dataset and then attempting

```
self.trainingDataSet = dataset( ... )
```

yields a diagnostic that a dict is not callable.
Carcigenicate was kind enough to explain that you probably want to call this constructor instead:

```
self.trainingDataSet = DataInputOutput( ... )
```